# Jasper reports font extension does not work on Spring boot with dedicated Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, fonts, jasper-reports

our app. is developed with Spring boot, the packaging type is war. We are running it both from command line "java -jar b2b.war" and on dedicated Tomcat. 
With Jasper reports, we got an error "Font Arial is not available to the JVM". Well, a known problem, we created font extension jar by Jasper Repost Studio and packed it into the war. Everything works on Windows after that, with both embedded and dedicated Tomcat. 
On Linux and dedicated Tomcat, we keep getting "Font Arial is not available" error. After installing msttcorefonts package, error disappeared, but PDF is generated w/o cyrillic characters, only English ones. That made me thinking that JVM ignores font extension and takes system fonts. But then I tried to run the same app on Linux with embedded Tomcat (java -jar b2b.war) - it worked fine! If, however, I manually remove font extension jar from war /WEB-INF/lib, cyrillic characters disappeared from report. So the extension does matter, at least with "java -jar" way of running.

Finally: on Linux, our font extension is working by "java -jar" launch (embedded Tomcat), and not working on dedicated Tomcat, with the same war and same JVM. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in Unix permissions, as often happens. 
Though Tomcat logs contains totally misleading exceptions:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.InvalidFontException: Error loading font "fonts/arial.ttf".
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.loadFont(SimpleFontFace.java:206) ~[jasperreports-6.4.0.jar:6.4.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.setTtf(SimpleFontFace.java:167) ~[jasperreports-6.4.0.jar:6.4.0]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFace(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:376) [jasperreports-6.4.0.jar:6.4.0]...
```

, the actual reason was that Java is unable to write to tomcat /temp directory. When I re-cretated temp with full access permissions to everyone, the report started to work fine.